# Issue with email verification via firebase in expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

According to [how to verify user email in firebase react native(Expo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703434/how-to-verify-user-email-in-firebase-react-nativeexpo). I can send a email verification right after I create a account in firebase via expo. But I am having trouble doing it.

Here is my code from my registerscreen file:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import {sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";

const RegisterScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
           try{
            const {user} = await sendEmailVerification(auth, email)
           }
           catch{
            
           }
           try{
            await signOut(auth)
            console.log("Signed out successfully")
            navigation.replace("Login")
          }catch (error) {
            console.log({error});
         }
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
    }
    return (
```

Currently the account is created but there is no email verification sent to the registered email. Can anyone help me out on this? Thank you very much.

Edited 1:

```
 try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(async 
                ({user}) => {
                // 2. Send verification email
                await user.sendEmailVerification()
                console.log("Verification email sent!")  
           })
           catch{

           }
           try{
            await signOut(auth)
            console.log("Signed out successfully")
            navigation.replace("Login")
          }catch (error) {
            console.log({error});
         }
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
```

The following gives me:
[image]

Also, the auto log in happened but did not log out of account

Edited 2:

```
try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)..then(async ({user}) => {
           // 2. Send verification email
           await user.sendEmailVerification()
           console.log("Verification email sent!") 
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
          
           try{
            await signOut(auth)
            console.log("Signed out successfully")
            navigation.replace("Login")
          }catch (error) {
            console.log({error});
         }
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
```

The above also doesn't work. It gives me : [image]

And the log out doesnt work anymore too. In this case, identical email can still be accepted somehow. I dont know why. But is isnt stored in firebase

Error from ```import firebase from 'firebase'
[image]

Currently my registerscreen.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import {sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";


const RegisterScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(async ({user}) => {
            auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
            console.log("Verification email sent!")  
        })
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
           
           try{
            await signOut(auth)
            console.log("Signed out successfully")
            navigation.replace("Login")
          }catch (error) {
            console.log({error});
         }
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
    }
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <Text>Email:</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />
            <Text></Text>
            <Text>Password:</Text>         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password (Min: 6 chars)"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />
            
            
        </View> 
        {showError && <View style={styles.error}>
          <Text>Email taken or password not valid - Min: 6 char</Text>
        </View>}        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleSignUp}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>                            
    </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
  )
}
```

Comment: There are many related links that you can look at. Based on your logs, it looks like your user might be null. Also, if you don't receive an email, make sure that you check your spam folder.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008874/react-native-check-user-email-with-sendemailverification-after-createuserwithema

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the verify after the user login using user instance like this:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, password).then(async ({user}) => {
  // 2. Send verification email
  await firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
  console.log("Verification email sent!")  
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am still having issues with it. Been playing around with the code but it is giving me different issues. I have updated the post. Is it possible to have a look at it and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: Can you try it like this

Comment: May I ask how do i deal with ```firebase```. It says cant find variable. I assume its something i have to import

Comment: `import firebase from 'firebase'`

Comment: I tried that just now but the whole app crashes

Comment: What the error you get?

Comment: I have posted the screenshot of my terminal at the bottom of my post

Comment: Change the import to this: `import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';`

Comment: auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()

Comment: Is there any difference from the auth that I have imported and I got the current error ```{"error": [TypeError: (0, _firebase.auth) is not a function. (In '(0, _firebase.auth)()', '(0, _firebase.auth)' is an instance of AuthImpl)]}```

Comment: can you post your final code

Comment: I have just posted it

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you did not complete the configuration of the `sendEmailVerification()`. It accepts an object argument.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)

```
.then(() => {
    auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification({
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      url : 'https://ENTER AUTHDOMAIN FROM YOUR FIREBASE CONFIGURATION'
    })
  })
```

Comment: There is no `sendEmailVerification` function in the link you have in the answer.